# apt-get python3.11 doesn't create pip3.11 command

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm updating a Docker container based on `public.ecr.aws/docker/library/alpine:latest`. Previously it installed Python versions 3.7 through 3.10. I need to install Python 3.11 on it. I'm not in a position to completely reconfigure this container, only to make necessary adjustments.

There's more being apt-got, but the Python packages are:

```bash
apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends \
        python3.7 \
        python3.7-dev \
        python3.7-distutils \
        python3.8 \
        python3.8-dev \
        python3.8-distutils \
        python3.9 \
        python3.9-dev \
        python3.9-distutils \
        python3.10 \
        python3.10-dev \
        python3.10-distutils \
        python3.11 \
        python3.11-dev
        python3.11-distutils \
```

This creates version-specific commands for each version of Python, eg. `python3.7` and `pip3.7`. But it does not create the command `pip3.11`.

- ```bash
  # pip3.11 -V
  bash: pip3.11: command not found
  ```
- ```bash
  # python3.11 -m pip -V
  pip 23.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pip (python 3.11)
  ```

Is there some installation step I need to run manually? I found [instructions to reinstall Pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#supported-methods), but that seems like overkill just to get the command linked correctly.

- `python3.11 -m ensurepip` does not work, the module does not exist.
- `curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.11` works, but as I said, it's a full reinstall of Pip.

Comment: I see there's a Close vote because this question should be migrated to another SX site. I'm guessing Server Fault is where this belongs? How do I migrate the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run as root:

```
python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score -1):

linux can be a bit confising sometimes. as an everyday linux user, I would have some ideas to help. see if there are any commands you can run as: pip, pip311 pip3

or you could try to run

sudo apt-get install python3-pip

sorry for my English I'm a native English speaker just a bit tired